# Suffix Array Construction O(N LogN) - Competitive Programming 3 Steven Halim

Tags: c, algorithm, suffix-array, counting-sort

I reading up the book Competitive Programming 3 by Steven Halim and Felix Halim

I'm reading the chapter on Strings.I'm trying to understand the suffix array construction algorithm. I dont understand the radix sort part.       (Although, I understand how radix sort and counting sort works)

Here is the code from the book

```
#define MAX_N 100010 // second approach: O(n log n)
char T[MAX_N]; // the input string, up to 100K characters
int n; // the length of input string

int RA[MAX_N], tempRA[MAX_N]; // rank array and temporary rank array
int SA[MAX_N], tempSA[MAX_N]; // suffix array and temporary suffix array

int c[MAX_N]; // for counting/radix sort

void countingSort(int k) { // O(n)

    int i, sum, maxi = max(300, n); // up to 255 ASCII chars or length of n
    memset(c, 0, sizeof c); // clear frequency table

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ // count the frequency of each integer rank
        c[i + k < n ? RA[i + k] : 0]++;
    }
    for (i = sum = 0; i < maxi; i++) {
        int t = c[i]; c[i] = sum; sum += t; 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ // shuffle the suffix array if necessary
        tempSA[c[SA[i]+k < n ? RA[SA[i]+k] : 0]++] = SA[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ // update the suffix array SA
        SA[i] = tempSA[i];
    }
}

void constructSA() { // this version can go up to 100000 characters
    int i, k, r;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) RA[i] = T[i]; // initial rankings
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) SA[i] = i; //initial SA: {0, 1, 2, ..., n-1}

    for (k = 1; k < n; k <<= 1) { // repeat sorting process log n times
        countingSort(k); //actually radix sort:sort based on the second item
        countingSort(0); // then (stable) sort based on the first item

        tempRA[SA[0]] = r = 0; // re-ranking; start from rank r = 0

        // compare adjacent suffixes
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++){
            // if same pair => same rank r; otherwise,increase r
            tempRA[SA[i]] = (RA[SA[i]] == RA[SA[i-1]] && RA[SA[i]+k] == RA[SA[i-1]+k]) ? r : ++r;           
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){// update the rank array RA
            RA[i] = tempRA[i];
        }

        if (RA[SA[n-1]] == n-1) break; // nice optimization trick
    } 
}
```

Can somebody please explain what is happening the in these lines of the countingSort() function?

```
for (i = sum = 0; i < maxi; i++) {
    int t = c[i]; c[i] = sum; sum += t; 
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ // shuffle the suffix array if necessary
    tempSA[c[SA[i]+k < n ? RA[SA[i]+k] : 0]++] = SA[i];
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ // update the suffix array SA
    SA[i] = tempSA[i];
}
```

Thanks a lot for your valuable time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First compute the startIndex for each unique ranking.

**REMARK:** `c[]` here stands for a ranking and not just for an individual character.

```
// compute cumulates of rankings
for (i = sum = 0; i < maxi; i++) {
    int t = c[i]; c[i] = sum; sum += t; 
}
```

Reorder the Suffix array using the just computed startIndices. Based on the ranking of the `SA[i]+k` suffix.

```
// shuffle the suffix array if necessary
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
    tempSA[c[SA[i]+k < n ? RA[SA[i]+k] : 0]++] = SA[i];
}
```

Copy back the updated values from the temp array

```
// copy the updated values back to SA
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
    SA[i] = tempSA[i];
}
```

---

This means that the suffix starting at position `i` is sorted by the ranking of the the suffix at place `(i+k)`.

We sort each suffix of length `k`, by the suffix of length `k` at place `i+k`. We can do this because at the previous iteration all suffixes were sorted for length `k`.

After that we sort again from the first index. Which was holding the ranking for size `k`. Since the [sorting is stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), all suffixes are now sorted for length `k*2`.

Our next step is to update the ranking if two contiguous suffix arrays in the ranking are not equal anymore.

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i++){
    // if same pair => same rank r; otherwise,increase r
    tempRA[SA[i]] = (RA[SA[i]] == RA[SA[i-1]] && RA[SA[i]+k] == RA[SA[i-1]+k]) ? r : ++r;           
}
```

If the ranking for size `k` at their `startIndex` is the same and the ranking at their `startIndex+k` is the same. Then the ranking at the `startIndex` is the same for size `k*2`.

This should also explain the following:

```
if (RA[SA[n-1]] == n-1) break; // nice optimization trick
```

This means that at that point the rankings for the current size are all unique. So all suffixes are unique as well and no further sorting is required.

---

### Stepped example:

```
  a   b   c   x   a   b   c   d 
--------------------------------INIT-
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 // SA
 97  98  99 120 97  98  99  100 // RA
---------------------------------K=1-
  0   2   5   7   1   3   4   6 // SA
  0   1   2   4   0   1   2   3 // RA
---------------------------------K=2-
  1   3   5   7   0   2   4   6 // SA
  1   3   5   7   0   2   4   6 // RA
```

#### countintSort Example for step K=1:

```
// count frequencies
c['a']=2;
c['b']=2;
c['c']=2;
c['d']=1;
c['x']=1;

// switch them to startindices
c['a']=0;
c['b']=2;
c['c']=4;
c['d']=6; // e.g. in total there are 6 suffixes smaller than starting with d (2 x a, 2 x b, 2 x c)
c['x']=7;

// determine the new SA position
tempSA[c[rank(SA[i]+k)]++] = SA[i];
// decomposing first iteration
tempSA[c[rank(SA[0]+k)]++] = SA[0]; // i = 0
tempSA[c[rank(SA[0]+1)]++] = SA[0]; // k = 1
tempSA[c[rank(1)]++] = 0; // SA[0] = 0
tempSA[c['b']++] = 0; // rank(1) = 'B'
tempSA[2] = 0; // c['b']=2 => 2++ = 3
```

In other words: put current first suffix array at the startIndex of the suffixArray that starts k places after. And increase that startIndex by one so the next occurence won't override.

```
// all other iterations resulting in:
tempSA[0] = 7 // d (sorted by EMPTY)
tempSA[1] = 3 // x (sorted by a)
tempSA[2] = 0 // a (sorted by b)
tempSA[3] = 4 // a (sorted by b)
tempSA[4] = 1 // b (sorted by c)
tempSA[5] = 5 // b (sorted by c)
tempSA[6] = 6 // c (sorted by d) 
tempSA[7] = 2 // c (sorted by d)

// last step is simply copying those values to SA (I suppose you know why this is)
```

This is all I can give you, if you still have troubles try to go through it with the debugger or print out subresults where you have doubts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Sam. If its possible can you please explain the steps in the counting sort procedure for the input "abcxabcd" ?

Thanks a ton for your time.

Comment: Also, can you please tell why '$' char is appended to the string ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422573/why-do-we-need-a-sentinel-character-in-a-suffix-tree

Comment: I tried to add some information about abcxabcd, but if that's still not clear. I recommend you to do some debugging with some examples where it's not clear for you.